# Should I install newest SCons version in Centos 5.4?

Tags: build-process, scons

I'm planning a new build system for our project running on Centos 5.4. I intend to use SCons. I noticed the latest stable SCons version is 2.0.1 while Centos 5.4 comes with 1.2.

I'm new to SCons so I'd like to understand more about the features/stability ratio between the versions.

Would you recommend installing and using the latest version or sticking to what comes from my OS repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 1.2 the [changes](http://www.scons.org/CHANGES-2.x.txt) have been bug fixes and documentation improvements. There haven't been any new features.

The 2.x version of SCons drops support for Python versions older than 2.4, updating some of the internal code to use newer idioms but without affecting any user visible APIs. That's the reason for the major version number change. If CentOS comes with a recent version of python then this won't affect you either way.

There have been a lot of fixes for newer versions of the various Microsoft compiler versions, but this won't affect a CentOS install.

The bug fixes since SCons 1.2.0 also solve problems in the Fortran, TeX and LaTeX builders. If you make use of Fortran or LaTeX then it would probably be worth upgrading. Otherwise I think you would be hard pushed to spot any day-to-day difference between 1.2.0 and 2.0.1.